# AS3 Error 1144: Method Implemented with Incompatible Signature

Tags: actionscript-3, osmf

I'm working with the OSMF library REOPS [https://code.google.com/p/reops/]. Particularly the REOPS.zip project files. [https://code.google.com/p/reops/downloads/detail?name=REOPS.zip]

When trying to compile the RE_Skin_Compiled.fla, I receive the following error:

ClosedCaptionField.as, Line 14, Column 15   1144: Interface method get text in namespace com.realeyes.osmfplayer.controls:IClosedCaptionField is implemented with an incompatible signature in class com.realeyes.osmfplayer.controls:ClosedCaptionField.

This error is detailed by Adobe here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/compilerErrors.html

Which states:

> Method signatures must match exactly.

There are only two methods in the IClosedCaptionField interface, and they do match what is implemented in the ClosedCaptionField class.

IClosedCaptionField.as

```
package com.realeyes.osmfplayer.controls
{
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

        public interface IClosedCaptionField extends ISkinElementBase
        {
                function get text():String;
                function set text(p_value:String):void;
        }
}
```

ClosedCaptionField.as

```
package com.realeyes.osmfplayer.controls
{
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;

    /**
     * Displays captions for media in the control bar. Accepts HTML
     * text (limited by Flash HTML display). This component starts
     * out invisible, and must be manually made visible.
     *
     * @author  RealEyes Media
     * @version 1.0
     */
    public class ClosedCaptionField extends SkinElementBase implements IClosedCaptionField
    {
        public var cc_txt:TextField;

        public function ClosedCaptionField()
        {
            super();

            //start up hidden
            //this.visible = false;
            //text = "";
        }

        /**
         * text
         * The HTML text to display
         *
         * @return      String
         */
        public function get text():String
        {
            return cc_txt.htmlText;
        }

        public function set text(p_value:String):void
        {
            if (cc_txt)
            {
                cc_txt.htmlText = p_value;
            }
            trace("set cc text: " + p_value);
        }
    }
}
```

In the RE_Skin_compiled.fla Actionscript Settings, I have added the path to the REOPS\src\ folder, and it is able to find the classes when checking the properties on the AS Linkage.

[image]

[image]

Any ideas on what I might be missing in order to get the RE_Skin_Compiled.fla to correctly compile along with it's skin classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the RE_Skin_compiled.fla, there is an included [underscore]code[underscore] compiled clip object which was causing the issues with conflicting classes.

After deleting the [underscore]code[underscore] compiled clip, the fla compiled with the linked classes correctly.